# Mariadb galera cluster with galera load balancer and master-slave replication: Errorno 1062 handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have the following setup in my environment.
Galera cluster with 2 nodes: `db01` and `db02`.

Server with galera load balancer installed: `glb01`, applications/clients connect to the cluster via port 8010 of `glb01`.

Now I would like to setup a backup server `db03` and configure master (galera cluster) <--> slave replication.

I followed the [link](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mariadb/master-slave-replication-galera-cluster) for the configuration.

`/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` mysqld unit in `db01`:

```
# Galera node as master
wsrep_gtid_mode      = on
wsrep_gtid_domain_id = 0
server-id            = 01
log_slave_updates    = on
log-bin              = /var/log/mysql/master-bin 
log-bin-index        = /var/log/mysql/master-bin.index
gtid_domain_id       = 1
```

`/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` mysqld unit in `db02`:

```
# Galera node as master
wsrep_gtid_mode      = on
wsrep_gtid_domain_id = 0
server-id            = 01
log_slave_updates    = on
log-bin              = /var/log/mysql/master-bin 
log-bin-index        = /var/log/mysql/master-bin.index
gtid_domain_id       = 2
```

`/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` mysqld unit in `db03`:

```
#Replication slave to Galera Cluster
server-id       = 02
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-bin.index
relay-log       = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-bin
gtid_domain_id  = 99

log-bin         = /var/log/mysql/slave-bin
log-bin-index   = /var/log/mysql/slave-bin.index
binlog_format   = mixed
```

Steps:

1.) In galera cluster master node create `replicant` user.

2.) Backup a database `testdb` from master node then copy to `db03` and restore it.

3.) Check the `gitd_binlog_pos` from master node.

```
show variables like 'gtid_binlog_pos';     # <--- result from db01
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| gtid_binlog_pos | 0-1-2 |
+-----------------+-------+

show variables like 'gtid_binlog_pos';     # <--- result from db02
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| gtid_binlog_pos | 0-1-61 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

4.) Run the slave in `db03`.

```
set global gtid_slave_pos = "0-1-2";     # <--- I'm using the gtid_binlog_pos from db01

change master to master_host=glb01,    # <--- using load balancer host to avoid single point of failure
master_user='replicant',
master_password='password',
master_port=8010,         
master_connect_retry=10,
master_use_gtid=slave_pos; 

start slave;
```

5.) Test the master-slave replication. Use mariadb client connect to `glb01:8010` and insert data to `testdb`. New data can be found in `db03`. Seems like everything working.

6.) Test failover by shutting down `db01`. Then connect to `glb01:8010` and insert new data, however, new data is not in sync in `db03` this time. Run `show slave status` gives the following error:

```
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: glb01
                   Master_User: replicant
                   Master_Port: 8010
                 Connect_Retry: 10
               Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1034
                Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.000003
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 629
         Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: No
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 1062
                    Last_Error: Could not execute Write_rows_v1 event on table testdb.table1; Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log master-bin.000002, end_log_pos 533
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 329
               Relay_Log_Space: 2097
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
                Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Write_rows_v1 event on table testdb.table1; Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log master-bin.000002, end_log_pos 533
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 1
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: Slave_Pos
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 0-1-62
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State:
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 2
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.